# Dynamically create table in Snowflake from another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to query TABLE_A to create TABLE_B in Snowflake.

TABLE_A:

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | string |
| col2 | timestamp |

TABLE_B should look like:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

I.e. the `name` values should become fields, the `type` values should define the data type for that field, and the table has no values.
But without referencing the column names (because this process is repeated for many tables), so I'm trying to make it dynamic.

I tried dynamic scripting with procedures in Snowflake, as below, but am running into syntax errors.

```
execute immediate $$
DECLARE
    ColumnName NVARCHAR;
    SELECT ColumnName = ISNULL(ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(column_names) + ' ' + column_types
    FROM (
        SELECT column_names, column_types 
        FROM metadata.v1_refined_config
        WHERE table_name = 'tickets'
        ) AS columns;
    dynSQL NVARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
    SELECT dynSQL = 'CREATE TABLE TEST_DYNAMIC ' + @ColumnName + '';
END;
$$
;
```

Errors:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 8 unexpected 'SELECT'. syntax error line 10 at position 15 unexpected 'NVARCHAR'. syntax error line 10 at position 23 unexpected '('.
```

Comment: Please update your question with what you have managed to write and the errors you are getting

Comment: You can try some thing like this CREATE table_A as select * from table_B where 1=0; where the table structure will be copied from table_B, How many tables you have if there are to o many then you can write a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
create or replace procedure SO_75150249(TABLE_NAMES varchar)
returns table(voila varchar)
language sql
as
$$
declare
    query2 varchar;
    res resultset;
    res1 resultset default 
    (SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_DYNAMIC AS SELECT '||LISTAGG(''''||DATA_TYPE||''''||'"'||COLUMN_NAME||'"',',')EASY FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = :TABLE_NAMES);
    cur1 cursor for res1;
begin
    for row_variable in cur1 do
            query2 := row_variable.EASY;
    end for;
    res := (execute immediate :query2);
    return table(res);
end;
$$;
```